# Not Getting Alarm on Boot Completed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my code i added all the permissions for Boot Completed  on Android manifest file..I logged My broadcast receiver,after reboot the control is going in to broadcast receiver But the alarm is not firing up.Actualy i want is a activity is launched after triggering alarm..In normal case(Before Shut down) i am getting the alarm and launched the activity..after reboot it is not happening...

this is my Boadcast receiver

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("hai", "inside onreceive");
    try {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {


                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,9);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,49);
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,
                            AlarmLauncher.class);
                    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent1.putExtra("alarm_message", "feathersoft Rules!");
                    // In reality, you would want to have a static variable
                    // for the request code instead of 192837
                    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                    Log.d("hai",
                            "alarm set");

                    // Get the AlarmManager service
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                            .getSystemService(context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    // am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    // cal.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                            sender);
                    Log.d("hai",
                            "Alarm Alert:Inside the boot completed broadcast receiver......");



                Log.d("hai",
                        "Alarm Alert:Inside the boot completed broadcast receiver......");
            }
        } 

    }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    "There was an error somewhere, but we still received an alarm",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    try {

    if(intent.getAction().equals(null))
        {

                SharedPreferences sp = context
                        .getSharedPreferences(
                                BigBirdConstants.nameOfPreference,
                                context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                String alrm = sp.getString(
                        BigBirdConstants.pref_myflight_alarm_time, "hello");
                Log.d("hai", alrm);
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmLauncher.class);
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                System.out.println("boot completed");
                // newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(newIntent);
            } 
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

This is my alarm dumpsys after reboot

```
$ dumpsys alarm
 dumpsys alarm
  Current Alarm Manager state:

  Realtime wakeup (now=1334031884759):
 RTC_WAKEUP #2: Alarm{460a6c88 type 0 com.android.providers.calendar}
  type=0 when=1334110692157 repeatInterval=0 count=0
  operation=PendingIntent{45dea300: PendingIntentRecord{460a6c10 com.android.p
roviders.calendar broadcastIntent}}
RTC_WAKEUP #1: Alarm{460eb1d0 type 0 com.google.android.gsf}
  type=0 when=1334073656706 repeatInterval=566387000 count=0
operation=PendingIntent{45d0d9c8: PendingIntentRecord{4606f3c0 com.google.an
droid.gsf broadcastIntent}}
  RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{4610cd88 type 0 com.google.android.gsf}
    type=0 when=1334032080140 repeatInterval=1800000 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{46057dc0: PendingIntentRecord{4610cd10 com.google.an
droid.gsf broadcastIntent}}
  RTC #1: Alarm{45ed7b10 type 1 android}
    type=1 when=1334082600000 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{45dd2c10: PendingIntentRecord{45e81c08 android broad
castIntent}}
  RTC #0: Alarm{461bf460 type 1 android}
    type=1 when=1334031900000 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{45cceb98: PendingIntentRecord{45f2b3e0 android broad
castIntent}}

  Elapsed realtime wakeup (now=527752):
  ELAPSED_WAKEUP #2: Alarm{46169c28 type 2 android}
    type=2 when=25881048 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{45d0c358: PendingIntentRecord{45cc99b0 android broad
castIntent}}
  ELAPSED_WAKEUP #1: Alarm{4610dc40 type 2 com.google.android.gsf}
    type=2 when=995077 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{460dd5c8: PendingIntentRecord{4610dbc8 com.google.an
droid.gsf broadcastIntent}}
  ELAPSED_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{46011b68 type 2 com.google.android.apps.maps}
    type=2 when=970384 repeatInterval=900000 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{45f9f478: PendingIntentRecord{45fea1d0 com.google.an
droid.apps.maps startService}}
  ELAPSED #1: Alarm{460da648 type 3 android}
    type=3 when=2557073343 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{45f84d38: PendingIntentRecord{45e34428 android broad
castIntent}}
  ELAPSED #0: Alarm{4609a418 type 3 android}
    type=3 when=727667 repeatInterval=0 count=0
    operation=PendingIntent{45f7da98: PendingIntentRecord{45e39420 android broad
castIntent}}

  Broadcast ref count: 0

  Alarm Stats:
  com.bigbird.Activity
    20ms running, 1 wakeups
    1 alarms: flg=0x10000004 cmp=com.bigbird.Activity/.AlarmLauncher
  com.google.android.gsf
    47ms running, 1 wakeups
    1 alarms: act=com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_RECONNECT flg=0x4
  android
    22819ms running, 3 wakeups
    1 alarms: act=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.DELAYED_KE
YGUARD flg=0x4
    8 alarms: act=android.intent.action.TIME_TICK flg=0x40000004
    2 alarms: act=android.content.syncmanager.SYNC_ALARM flg=0x4
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem

in the pending intent i am used the activity to be launched..thats the fault..in pending intent u should use your Broadcast receiver as intent...

```
if (sp.getBoolean(BigBirdConstants.pref_alarm_set, false)) {
                String alrm = sp.getString(
                        BigBirdConstants.pref_myflight_alarm_time, "hello");
                String alrmtime[] = new String[2];


                    alrmtime = alrm.split(":");

                    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    /*
                     * Integer.parseInt(alrmtime[
                     * 0])
                     */
                    /* Integer.parseInt(alrmtime[1]) */
                    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,13);
                    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,
                            AlarmReceiver.class);
                    intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent1.putExtra("alarm_message", "feathersoft Rules!");
                    // In reality, you would want to have a static variable
                    // for the request code instead of 192837
                    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 192837, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    Log.d("hai",
                            "alarm set");
```